# what is this thing?

Tags: tomatoes

I am quite new to taking care of plants and I do need some advice regarding brown scale-like stuff on the stem of my tomato plant. ( yes, I tried googling the problem)

Backgrounder:
re-potted - a month ago
Fertilizer- 2 weeks ago
bought from a big box store 2 months ago
watering- when 1" top soil dry

Thanks for all the help.

Manuel

[image: Plant]

[image: Plant]

Answer (score 1):

I believe they're scars. I can't say for sure what the cause is, but it looks like they might be from pill bugs, slugs, or some other critter nibbling on it. It doesn't look like something to be terribly concerned about. It could alternatively be cause by abrasion, or some such.

Some extra potassium (not accompanied by nitrogen) might help to deter further munching, by strengthening the stems.

If the plant is in low light it'll probably be more susceptible to problems like this. If you put it in stronger sun, you may want to do it gradually.

If the initial layer of skin on the plant is still present, but raised and brown, then I believe it's a different problem altogether (since nothing could have chewed it off).